# Dynamically changing width accordingly to database value

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a database with lots of records and I have to make a foreach loop in order to get all that data. The problem is that a chart for every data would overload the page. So I need to make a barlike chart using two divs and one div(the blue one) to take percentage of the main one (the grey div) accourding to the value from that data. I did all of that but I don't know how to make the inner div build change it's percentage width according to how close it is from the highest value in my database. This is how I fetch the numbers shown in the right.

```
<?php echo @$item->{"media_count"}; ?>
```

I will attach an image so you can see how I need to make it look like.
[barlike chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjJ2.png)

```
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody style="width: 401px; border: 0;">
         <?php foreach ($data->data->data as $key => $item):
            if (@$item->{"name"}) {
          ?>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo @$item->{"name"}; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="outer">
                            <div class="inner" style="width: 20%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo @$item->{"media_count"}; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
        <?php }
        endforeach ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And the CSS for the inner and outer divs:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .outer, .inner {
      height: 14px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .outer {
      background-color: #cccccc;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .inner {
      background-color: #66a3ff;

    }

td {
    border:none;
}
table {
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}


</style>
```

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you want the percentage of all the bars to be relative to the highest value in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things I'm not quite sure about in your code (like the use of the error suppression operators), but I think the code below will give you a nice working example of how to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
<?php
    $max = 1;
    foreach( $data->data->data as $tmp )
        $max = ( ( $tmp->media_count > $max )? $tmp->media_count: $max );
?>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody style="width: 401px; border: 0;">
<?php
    foreach( $data->data->data as $item ){
        if( $item->name ){
            $percent = $item->media_count / $max;
?>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $item->name ); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="outer">
                            <div class="inner" style="width: <?php echo round( 100 * $percent) ?>%;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo htmlspecialchars( $item->media_count ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Depending on how you are retrieving your data, there's probably a lot more efficient way for you to get the max of your data than looping through the whole structure, but, since you didn't show us how your data is retrieved in the original question, I took the only approach I had.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. I am sorry for the lack of complete info.

Comment: Always glad to do what I can. Turns out there was enough info to get your code working, so it's all good.